# ValueTuple naming conventions

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, c#-7.0

When naming a ValueTuple element, should they be capitalized or not?

```
(string Name, int Index) rec;
```

or

```
(string name, int index) rec;
```

**EDIT:**

It seems the convention is PascalCase

See: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27939#issuecomment-531420515

**EDIT 2:**

I chose to always use camelCase. I see 'ValueTuple' as just a bag of values used almost exclusively for returning multiple values from functions. I never use ValueTuple as a state and always prefer `records` for that.
.

Comment: hmm, this is hard, i found online example that uses the [lowercase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt493248.aspx) one but it uses PascalCase on some.. but really, coding convention is depend on where you put the code..

Comment: To be consistent with `Tuple` properties `Item1` and `Item2`, it would be capitalized.

Comment: Yes but Paulo below also has valid reasoning ..

Comment: [Sadly, this looks set to become a source of conflicting advice](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33553). The C# language team have always favoured `(string name, int index)` in all the code examples I've seen from them. Unfortunately, the BCL team look set to adopt `(string Name, int Index)` though. Hopefully they'll reconsider and we can all agree on the former being the "right" choice.

Comment: @Jasen, the fact that tuples are `Tuple` structs under the hood is just an implementation detail. To my mind, that isn't a valid reason for using CamelCase with the tuple syntax, which hides away that implementation detail.

Comment: @kofifus even [Microsoft's core developers can't agree](https://twitter.com/terrajobst/status/1063560341836070912) on naming conventions. The only thing they agree on is that ValueTuple should probably not be used in public APIs. Everywhere else, the name doesn't really matter

Comment: @kofifus there's a BUT of course - with record types postponed, tuples are still the only way to return multiple values, eg similar to Go's results.

Comment: While this might be considered "primarily opinion based" at the moment, it *shouldn't* be, and should be reopened. Suggested naming conventions are mostly well-defined in C#, and I suspect this is only a temporary exception to that.

Comment: `Item1` and `Item2` should have been enough to decide that it should be PascalCase

Comment: The question is not opinion based anymore - dotnet/bcl team agreed on PascalCase, and this question should be reopened and added a new CORRECT answer. References: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27939#issuecomment-531420515
https://github.com/terrajobst/minsk/pull/151#discussion_r430134358
https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1316.md#rule-description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at tuple as bags of variables and, as such, the convention is to use camel case.

Comment: would that still hold for ie: List<(int index, string name)> ? here it feels more of a struct than a bag of vars ?

Comment: A tuple is a bag of values/variables. `List<(int index, string name)>` is a list of bags of variables.

Comment: +1 One of the design principles of tuples was that they should mirror argument lists—again, a bag of variables.

Comment: I disagree. They should use Pascal case. What matters is how tuples values are *used*. They're used like public fields or properties by the caller, and to the caller the fact that they're in a Tuple and not a Class is irrelevant. Using camel case here is Hungarian notation IMO.

Wish I could post an answer, this should be reopened :/

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33553

Comment: @PauloMorgado thanks for linking that issue and showing that its indeed should be pascal case

Comment: @PauloMorgado well the camelCase camp was okay with unnamed tuples using PascalCase, the PascalCase camp thought its better to not use tuples at all in public APIs than to use camelCase because it will confuse users

Comment: It's not about camps but intent of the feature. And the members of the C# team explained the intent and why it should be camelCase. .NET team members, as brilliant as they are, developed a perception that they can't shake now. And the decision was that everyone has more important things to deal with now.

Comment: Note in that linked GitHub issue, there's no consensus in or out of the .NET team which is "correct", it's a point of contention. However, they're going to continue to use PascalCase in their public APIs, so unless you want your APIs to be different than the frameworks, use PascalCase.

Comment: @JoshNoe, do you have an example of such APIs?

Comment: @PauloMorgado they reference ```public static IEnumerable<(TFirst First,TSecond Second)> Zip<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second)``` as the reason the github issue you linked to was opened. At the end of this issue, they're basically saying that they've used PascalCase so far, so they'll continue to. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @JoshNoe, that's the opinion of C# users, not "they're going to continue to use PascalCase in their public APIs". I value the opionion of the motivation for the feature and their creators (mainly, Mads Torgersen and Neal Gafter). On that example, tuple values equate to `out` parameters. So, it's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

[image: tuple example]

Since the variables are handled as members of the tuple, they should be named using pascal-case.

Answer (score 0):

The StyleCop convention is to use PascalCase for tuples:

[SA1316TupleElementNamesShouldUseCorrectCasing](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1316.md)

The dotnet/bcl team agreed on PascalCase:

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27939#issuecomment-531420515
- https://github.com/terrajobst/minsk/pull/151#discussion_r430134358

> We decided to go with PascalCase for one reason: usage. When accessing tuple members, they should behave like any other public field/property, which is PascalCase. This also makes it easier to refactor the code from tuples to custom types. So yeah, PascalCasing is the correct casing for tuples.